# Mongodb - sorting elements of an array returning complete document

Tags: mongodb

Mongo document :

```
{
    "id": "5537736f74d2d3a413b7abcf",
    "userId": "1",
    "tripName": "default",
    "friends": [
        {
            "name": "f",
            "dob": "2015-05-01"         
        },
        {
            "name": "e",
            "dob": "2015-07-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "d",
            "dob": "2015-06-01"
        }
    ],

    "relatives": [
        {
            "name": "c",
            "dob": "2015-05-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "dob": "2015-07-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "a",
            "dob": "2015-06-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired output :

```
{
    "id": "5537736f74d2d3a413b7abcf",
    "userId": "1",
    "tripName": "default",
    "friends": [
        {
            "name": "d",
            "dob": "2015-07-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "e",
            "dob": "2015-05-01"         
        },        
        {
            "name": "f",
            "dob": "2015-06-01"
        }
    ],

    "relatives": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "dob": "2015-05-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "dob": "2015-07-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "c",
            "dob": "2015-06-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort both friends array and relatives array on name field and return the complete document.

how can I unwind two arrays, please help me out in writing appropriate query to solve the above problem.

Thanks
Babu

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary to perform the sort in the database, you can always retrieve the document as is then sort the arrays after the query.

You might want to think about storing those arrays in order in the first place if it's important that they are already sorted when obtaining the object from the database.